# Unable to disable Gutenberg with plugin Classic Editor or Disable Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I updated my Wordpress to version 5.0

After updating, I install "Classic Editor" plugin to replace Gutenberg.

The post editor changed to Classic Editors.

Today I received a mail my site is updating to Wordpress 5.0

My post editor became Gutenberg.

I checked the setting is Classic Editors, but it still Gutenberg.

I tried "disable Gutenberg" plugin and activated it.

No changes to my post editor, it still Gutenberg.

How to change it back to Classic Editor?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: how does your page-overview look? each page has a little description now if block or classic editor is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the new WordPress 5.0 update, I was able to switch between the classic editor & Gutenberg without installing the "Disable Gutenberg" extension. Looking at the release notes for the "Disable Gutenberg" plugin, it [states](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/):

*"Do not use Disable Gutenberg with other plugins (like the Classic Editor plugin) that also disable or replace Gutenberg. Why? Because it may cause loading of redundant scripts, which may in turn lead to unexpected/untested results."*

You stated you are running the Classic Editor plugin with "Disable Gutenberg". This is the conflict. Otherwise, clear your cache in the CMS & browser to see if it makes any difference.

**Solution:**

1. Without installing the "Disable Gutenberg" plugin, navigate to the classic editor settings at: /wp-admin/options-writing.php#classic-editor-options
2. Under the settings for "Default editor for all users" use the buttons to toggle between 'Classic Editor' & 'Block Editor' (Gutenberg). Save the settings & reload the page.

Comment: I tried disable "Disable Gutenberg" plugin. When I click on new post, it still display Gutenberg editor. I need to change it in option to classic editor.

Comment: You may need to uninstall the WP Posts module to see if that makes a difference or is causing the conflict.